# CruiseControl.net sporadically fails to pull from Git

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I have a CruiseControl.net server which keeps reporting broken builds with the message "Failing Tasks : Git: CheckForModifications"

The exception given in the log is:

> ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   Process command: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.cmd fetch origin

What is really odd is that this error does not occur all the time. Forcing a build causes CC to pull correctly and keep on working for a while (until this happens again).

Some other information that could be relevant:

- This happens with more than one source for Git (I've tried GitHub and Beanstalk)
- This is happening on several servers, both locally hosted and on the AWS cloud
- Authentication is using an SSH key with no passphrase

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this is the same as your problem, but I've seen a similar issue occasionally when CC is trying to pull from SVN over HTTPS. I solved it by routing that traffic around the corporate proxy, which was sometimes killing the connection if it took longer than a few seconds to respond.

Comment: That's a good idea. I don't think that is the case here, as we're not using a proxy locally, and (as far as I know) the AWS server doesn't use one either.

Answer (score 0):

The interval time of CheckForModifications is probably long and the ssh connection closes and on re-open occasionally fails! 
You could try adding the following to your **.ssh/.gitconfig** file, that way all ssh connections will send a 'keep alive' every 30 seconds and keep the connections always active.

```
KeepAlive = yes
ServerAliveInterval = 30
```